# Redirect to different directories depending on condition

Tags: php

I want to modify a logout trigger in my CMS, by redirecting a user to a different directory upon a condition. Basically, I have my CMS, and outside of it on a subdomain `m.site_url.com` I have a mobile version of the site.

Logically, it makes sense to redirect a user to mobile version's home page if they log out on the mobile site. Likewise, same would go for the CMS on a PC.

```
class Logout extends CodonModule 
{
    public function index()
    {
        Auth::LogOut();
        header('Location: '.url('/'));
    }
}
```

The above logs out the user and redirects it to specified `url`, which is the homepage of the CMS. I would therefore like an if/else statement, if an user is logging out on the subdomain, they will get redirected to subdomain's index page. How can I do this? I've tried to detect the URL and redirect them upon that, but I feel I'm failing miserably.

I'd like ideally a solution which I could apply to various other aspects. It could become vital during login process. Normally, if the password is wrong, a message page from the CMS is displayed, but again, it would be pointless to redirect a mobile user to a desktop site etc.

```
class Logout extends CodonModule 
{
    public function index()
    {

        Auth::LogOut();

        $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if (false !== strpos($url,'m.site')) {
        {
        header('Location: http://m.site_url.com/index.php');
        }
        else
        {
        header('Location: '.url('/'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of the subdomain using:

```
$sub_domain = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

And use that to determine if you're currently in a subdomain, and if so what one - and act accordingly.

EDIT:

```
class Logout extends CodonModule 
{
    public function index()
    {

    $sub_domain = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));

    die($sub_domain); //debug the value

    if($sub_domain == 'm')
    {
        Auth::LogOut();
        header('Location: http://m.site_url.com/index.php');
    }
    else
    {
        Auth::LogOut();
        header('Location: '.url('/'));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would I then use something like `if (false !== strpos($subdomain,'m.')) {` or not?

Comment: You'd check if $sub_domain == 'm', the reason being that explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) will turn a domain with a subdomain into an array, using the '.' as a seperator, so 1 element will contain the bit before the '.' [the sub domain] and another the main domain. array_shift() on this array will shift the first element off it and return it to $sub_domain, so if it's on your mobile site $sub_domain will === 'm' else it's not.

Comment: So `if (false !== strpos($subdomain,'m')) {` ?

Comment: simply if($sub_domain == 'm') { //it's mobile site , there are loads of ways to achieve the same thing here

Comment: I tried it but it still redirects to main site, any ideas? Edited the post.

Comment: I'd die($sub_domain) after declaring and just before the if else statements to check what it's value is to debug

Comment: I see your error, $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; should be $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: It is, I've added the updated version right at the bottom `$sub_domain = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));` still not working.

Comment: It returns `flyeurova`

Comment: does that make sense to you?

Comment: It printed out the value above, and stopped the script, correct? I am guessing that is the main domain, how can I fix the redirect to the subdomain?

Comment: No need to guess, is 'flyeurova' part of the domain name? If so what part and what's the full domain

Comment: Yes, flyeurova.com is the full domain.

Comment: Ok so if it's returning flyteurova then your not in the sub domain. remove the die(), it kills the script and prints the value inside - useful for debugging

Comment: The script is executed from the subdomain however. Could it be because the directory for this subdomain is `/mobile`? I've removed the die, what next?

Comment: I think your misunderstanding the principle, the function I originally suggested will provide you with one of two things, if it's executed on a subdomain, then it will provide you with the name of the subdomain, in your case 'm', else it will provide you with the domain name, and you can act accordingly to this information, just use that value in your redirection. I don't see what the issue is